# Setting javadocExecutable from command line does not work

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, javadoc, maven-javadoc-plugin

I am execution a project with Java 6 (latest public Oracle release) and Maven 3.2.5. I want the Javadoc generated with Java 8. When configuring with this setup, everything works fine:

```xml
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10.3</version>
    <configuration>
        ...
        <javadocExecutable>/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javadoc</javadocExecutable>
        <additionalparam>-Xdoclint:none</additionalparam>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

However, if I omit the `<javadocExecutable>` element and try the same from the command line, it fails (Java 6 is used as reported by Maven):

```
$ mvn release:prepare -DjavadocExecutable=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javadoc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because the `prepare` goal of `maven-release-plugin` runs a forked build and the system properties are not copied in the fork.

You need to use the [`arguments`](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments) attribute, like this:

```
mvn release:prepare -Darguments="-DjavadocExecutable=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle/bin/javadoc"
```

Quoting from its documentation:

> Additional arguments to pass to the Maven executions, separated by spaces.